Is there a C# .NET 6 equivalent thing that restricts type param to arithmetic type like C++ std::is_arithmetic_v<T>?
I know there exists type constraint syntax in C# like this:
public float foo<T>(T a) where T : IEnumerable<T> { //... }

And for .NET 7 there exists generic math.
Is there an equivalent thing in .NET6?
I tried to add <EnablePreviewFeatures>true</EnablePreviewFeatures> in my .csproj file but it didn't work.

No. .net 6 is also out of support

If it existed in .NET 6 what would be the point of adding it in .NET 7?

This feature required static interface members which requires runtime (not just library) support, and requires lots of types in the framework libraries to implement those new interfaces. So no, it doesn't exist in .net 6, and cannot be backported. There are a range of hacks and workarounds - reflection, dynamic, per-type special-casing, etc - that have been used for many years, but they're nowhere near the full API.
